# Permanantly disable Activities hot corner

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gestures

I am Trying to disable the top-left activities hot corner but after a lock-unlock, it gets enabled again.

So, the question is not how to disable it. I know how to do it via Tweaks tool as well as the command-line. The question is about how to disable it, and ensure that it stays disabled because it basically is kind of annoying.

Comment: It *should be* disabled permanently if you use Tweaks or command-line.

Comment: Nope. Seems to be a bug. It enables itself after lock-unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the extension [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) and you're done.

Comment: I downloaded the .zip file, extracted it to ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions path. But the extension does not show up in Tweaks tool even after restarting gnome-shell, logout-login, restart, etc. Have also tried moving it to /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions location but no luck whatsoever.

Comment: Just flip the off/on switch on the website. It should turn it on if the browser is configured correctly.

Comment: Oh... That would require installation of Firefox... I don't like that and it does not work from Chromium. Or does it?

Comment: There's a way to enable chromium gnome extensions integration. More information: https://www.fossmint.com/install-gnome-shell-extensions/

Comment: Nice! Able to configure extensions from Chromium now. And the extension works as expected as well! Thank you!